# how to compute how much memory a process is using?

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, process, xperf

I would like to know, how much cumulative memory a process is using?

I am analyzing my system's performance during a large copy operation.
In that, I am targeting few processes.

I want to calculate how much memory they use during that time and if some process is using significant memory, I wanted to dig into it (any memory leak or piece of code which is causing memory overhead).

I have tried using xperf commands.

In xperf command, I have used following kernel flags

```
->MEMORY+MEMINFO+MEMINFO_WS+HARD_FAULTS+VIRT_ALLOC+VAMAP+FOOTPRINT+REFSET
```

& stackwalk flags

```
->PageAccess+PageAccessEx+PageRelease+PageRangeAccess+PageRangeRelease+VirtualAlloc+VirtualFree+HardFault+HeapCreate+HeapFree+HeapAlloc+HeapDestroy+HeapRealloc+PagefileMappedSectionCreate+PagefileMappedSectionDelete
```

In the resulted etl, I can see following tabs in left pane under memory.
Memory utilization: this is of no use because this does not contain any process related data.

Hard faults: Page faults by process
Virtual alloc commit life times: Outstanding commit by process
Pool Graphs: Paged data and Non-paged data
Resident Set:

1. Default
2. Memory Pressure
3. Physical Memory Pressure
4. Process Private Working Set

Please enlighten me about which tabs/parameters to consider for memory usage.
How do I use this data to conclude about memory usage\memory leaks\ API name that is causing higher memory utilization by loading symbols ?

Comment: @magicandre1981

Comment: use **wpr.exe -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout 3 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighMemoryUsage.etl**. Drag & drop [Resident Graph](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-154-Memory-Footprint-and-Leaks#time=10m37s) to analyzes pane to see the usage

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry But this command is giving me error. "The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: 0x80070002". PS. I am using windows 7.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can you please check above command once again. Because you wrote "Reference Set" in command and the link is for Resident Set analysis. And I think these two are quite different.

Comment: ReferenceSet works since Windows 8. Change command to ResidentSet.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Resident is working on windows 7. Now I can see Resident Set tab in left pane under Memory tab.

Comment: @magicandre1981 There are 4 appearances for this.
1. Default
2. Memory Pressure
3. Physical Memory Pressure
4. Process Private Working Set
Please enlighten me about which tabs/parameters to consider for memory usage. 
How do I use this data to conclude about memory usage\memory leaks\ API name that is causing higher memory utilization by loading symbols ?